# What does "marked for branch" mean in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I am copying a child stream up into a parent and a few of the files are set as `marked for branch`

[image]

and some are set to `marked for branch deleted in deleted at head revision`.

[image]

I have looked everywhere and I can't find any documentation on what these status values actually mean. I'm guessing it means it's going to create a new file in the parent stream. The ones that have `deleted at head revision` in them are files that used to exist in the parent stream but were deleted. I'm now copying them back into the parent from the child.

Is that the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  "Marked" is P4V's language for what is called "opened" in the rest of Perforce.